# Selenium -- find element

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Explain what is the difference between `find_element_by_xpath(my_xpath)` and `find_element(By.XPATH, my_xpath)`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

source = "https://github.com/"
my_xpath = '/html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/img'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(source)
x = driver.find_element_by_xpath(my_xpath)
y = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, my_xpath)
driver.quit()
```

In debugger I see the similar objects x and y:

[image]

Comment: There is no difference in output, but difference in managing your objects: `find_element()` gives you more flexibility as you can create `locator = By.XPATH, my_xpath` somewhere and use it as `find_element(*locator)` in, for example, your tests. You can simply update locator `locator = By.CSS, my_css` and there will be no need in updating your test code as `find_element(*locator)` is still valid...

Comment: Moreover, having set `locator` you can use it with WebDriverWait and expected conditions. For example `WebDriverWait(driver).until(expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located(locator))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference.

The function `find_element_by_xpath(some_xpath)` is just a convenience shortcut for `find_element(By.XPATH, some_xpath)`.

If you were to read [the source](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/ec681f22d15262ed3bfa91d65b889c3dc003c9eb/py/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py#L322-L351) you would find the function `find_element_by_xpath` actually calls `find_element`

```
def find_element_by_xpath(self, xpath):
    '''docstring omitted for brevity on SO'''
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
```

It is, right down to the source, exactly the same.

Comment: Nice explanation, upvoted  !!!